# Issue in placing textarea on canvas in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, jtextarea

I'm trying to place the textarea content into canvas but getting undefined message instead on the canvas block. successfully loaded image on it but not textarea. i tried in many ways to solve this but could not solve. please help me. Thanks in Advance.

html code

```
<textarea>praise the lord</textarea>
<div > <button class="wrapper1" id="saveid" onclick="sharee(0)">SAVE </button> </div>

<img id="scream" src="a.jpg" alt="The Scream" width="70" height="70"><p>Canvas:</p>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="300" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
```

javascript code

```
function sharee() {  
var val = document.getElementById("myCanvas");

 var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
     var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var img = document.getElementById("scream");
 textArea = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0],

ctx.font="30px Arial";
ctx.drawImage(img, 40, 40);
ctx.fillText(textarea, 40,60);
setTimeout(function(){
   window.savephotoplugin(canvas,"image/png",device.version,function(val){ 
        //returns you the saved path in val 
        alert("Photo Saved: " + val);   
    });
 }, 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to draw the `textarea` element it self as text which won't work.

Try this modification:

```
ctx.fillText(textArea.value, 40, 60);
```

and I'm not sure if this is just a typo in the post, but this line needs to be:

```
var textArea = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0]; //no comma at end
```